# eBPF Maps: How to update using bpftool from command line

Tags: kernel, c

I am using `tc` to attach my **eBPF** (C code compiled using clang), to network.

I am using **eBPF Maps** to store some data.

Specifically, I am using `bpf_map_update_elem` to update **eBPF Maps** from within the BPF Program, but I want to also change the contents of the map **from outside** the program.

Map **structure**:

```
struct rt_val {
    int ifaceno;
    int macaddr[6];
};
union key_4 {
    __u32 b32[2];
    __u8 b8[8];
};
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") lpm_map_fwd = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_LPM_TRIE,
    .key_size = 8,
    .value_size = sizeof(struct rt_val),
    .max_entries = 50,
    .map_flags = BPF_F_NO_PREALLOC,
};
```

Map updation, and lookup are fine.

> But i want to dynamically change the contents of the eBPF Map, from outside the program execution.

Any comments/suggestion regarding the same would be much **appreciated!**

Resources:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html

System Specifics:

- `uname -r`: 4.15.0-47-generic
- `OS`: Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already found all the tools you need to update eBPF maps from user space.

## `bpf()`

The `bpf(cmd, attr, size)` system call is used to perform the update. The `cmd` passed as first argument indicates what type of operation you want to perform: in your case, that would be `BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM`. Then the manual page you linked explains how to build `attr`: in your case (for map updates), it should be:

```
struct {    /* Used by BPF_MAP_*_ELEM and BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_KEY commands */
        __u32         map_fd;
        __aligned_u64 key;
        union {
                __aligned_u64 value;
                /* [...] */
        };
        __u64         flags;
};
```

Meaning you should build a `union bpf_attr` and pass it the file descriptor to the map, the key of the entry you want to update, the new value for that key, and possibly some flags.

The file descriptor for the map can be obtained:

- from the path under the BPF virtual file system, if the map has been pinned beforehand,
- from the id of the map, with another call to the `bpf()` system call, using the `BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID` command,
- (or as a return value from the call to `bpf()` that created the map, but not in the case you used tc to load the program).

Note that libbpf ([shipped with kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/) or [mirrored on GitHub](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf)) provides wrappers around the `bpf()` system call and can make things easier.

## bpftool

In practice, you do not need to reimplement all of this. As you mentioned in the title, bpftool allows you to update maps from command line, without having to reimplement the whole process.

### Get bpftool

**Edit:** On Ubuntu 19.10 (eoan), bpftool is packaged as part of the `linux-tools-common` package. Read below for instructions for older releases.

As of this writing, bpftool has [not](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896165) been packaged for Debian/Ubuntu, which means that you have to build it from source. It is shipped with the kernel, so it takes time to download, but building is actually very simple:

```
 $ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
 $ cd linux
 $ cd tools/bpf/bpftool
 $ make
(# make install)
(# make doc doc-install)
```

Alternatively, there is an unofficial version packaged [on this page](https://help.netronome.com/support/solutions/articles/36000050009-agilio-ebpf-2-0-6-extended-berkeley-packet-filter) (disclaimer: from my company). The packaged binary was statically built and should work on all x86_64 Linux machines.

### Update maps

After that, you can use it to list the maps currently existing on your system:

```
# bpftool -f map show
```

The ids of each map will be displayed on the left. Find the id related to the map you want to update (or if the map was pinned, note its path, displayed with the `-f` option), and then use one of:

```
# bpftool map update id <id> key <key> value <new_value>
# bpftool map update pinned <path> key <key> value <new_value>
```

For example:

```
# bpftool map update id 17 key 0x1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 value 0x1 0x2 0x3...
```

(Note: I would use an array of `__u8`s rather than `int`s for storing a MAC address in your `struct rt_val`. Your `macaddr` is likely to count for 24 bytes.)

In case you are unsure of how values are stored in the map, do not hesitate to dump it in the console:

```
# bpftool map dump id 17
```

### More resources

I do not know of any existing bpftool tutorial, but you can find all the details [in the manual pages](https://www.mankier.com/package/bpftool) for the tool. I also wrote some tips about it [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/qeole/status/1101450782841466880).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Qeole, it was really helpful

Comment: @anuraagtummanapally Glad to here that! If it fully answered your question, you might want to “accept” the answer (Otherwise, you may want to provide additional precisions on whatever is left to solve).

Comment: How can one pin BPF MAP from kernel space, because `bpf_obj_pin()` is used in userspace?

And also, the way I have created my BPF MAP, how can I know the id of the BPF MAP?

Comment: You don't pin it from kernel space, only from user side. Usually you get the map id as the return value from `bpf()`, but if you use `tc` that won't do. I see three ways: 1) use `bpftool map show` to list maps (and their ids) and find yours, 2) use the mechanism provided by `tc` (search for `file descriptor` in `tc-bpf` man page) [probably not the recommended solution], or 3) create and pin the maps beforehand with bpftool, have your program reuse them when being loaded with `tc`. I'd go for 1), unless you need to do it programmatically (then I'd go for 3) ).

Comment: Great!, I want to follow 3).
Sorry for long discussions, but how can one use a pinned bpf map in kernel space.

Comment: Oooh sorry I forgot `tc` can pin maps too. So you probably don't have to use bpftool to create the maps. Just use `tc` and set the `.pinning` attribute for your map to `PIN_GLOBAL_NS` (see [this example](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/examples/bpf/bpf_shared.c)). On loading the program, `tc` should probe the system for a map with the same name and specifications under `/sys/fs/bpf/tc/globals/` and reuse it, if available, instead of creating a new map. So you can launch your program and pin the map, and feed that pinned path to bpftool later for map update.